# css conform text to avoid background image

Tags: html, css

I have a page background design that has a triangle in the top right that looks odd to have text overlap.  I'd like to dynamically conform any elements in the page to avoid this area.  The best I've come up with thus far is to have a number of elements floated and cleared.

For example:

```
#content{
  display: block;
}
corner{
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

<div id="content">
  <corner style="height:20px;width:142px;"></corner>
  <corner style="height:20px;width:129px;"></corner>
  <corner style="height:20px;width:116px;"></corner>
  <corner style="height:20px;width:103px;"></corner>
  ...
  <corner style="height:20px;width:12px;"></corner>

  <p><img style="width:240px;height:135px;float:left;margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;" />lorem ipsum...</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

```css
#content{
  display: block;
}
corner {
  display: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
 <corner style="height:20px;width:142px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:129px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:116px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:103px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:90px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:77px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:64px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:51px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:38px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:25px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:12px;"></corner>
<p>
<img style="background-color:green;width:240px;height:135px; float:left; margin:0px 5px 0px 0px" />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that the image is also cleared past the `corner` elements.  If you add `display:none` to the corner style, the image is correctly floated left with all text wrapped (but I obviously lose the corner).  Is there a way I can achieve both aspects of this?

Comment: is this what you are trying? https://jsfiddle.net/dt5Lfpag/

Comment: Can you put the `img` before the corner? As in are you allowed to in the markup

Comment: Yes, I could move the img, which does work in this simplified case.  However, try putting the image at the top-left of the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer... change the orientation!  Instead of horizontal boxes with decreasing widths, use vertical boxes with decreasing height.  Then you don't need to clear them.

```css
#content{
  display: block;
}
corner {
  display: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
 <corner style="height:220px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:200px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:180px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:160px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:140px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:120px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:100px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:80px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:60px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:40px;width:13px;"></corner>
 <corner style="height:20px;width:13px;"></corner>
<p>
<img style="background-color:green;width:240px;height:135px; float:left; margin:0px 5px 0px 0px" />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
```